# How to Rebind MVC Core 2 ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to rebind modelstate validation in controller?

I have the following:

```
        if (!model.DifferentShippingAddress)
        {
            model.ShippingAddress = model.BillingAddress.ToShipping();
            // Rebind modelstate
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
```

I want to skip ShippingAddress entries if a "SameAsBilling" checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#handle-model-state-errors) for Model validation reads the following:

> Model validation occurs before the execution of a controller action.

Therefore, you need to clear the `ModelState` and manually trigger the validation using the code from below.

```
if (!model.DifferentShippingAddress)
{
    model.ShippingAddress = model.BillingAddress.ToShipping();
    ModelState.Clear();
    TryValidateModel(model);
}
```